# Master page error in subsite

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am inheriting a master page from site collection. The master page is having a dataview web part embedded inside it. The data view web part shows a list of the site collection. In the site collection level this is working fine but in subsite its giving error in master page as the list is present in the site collection.

Has anybody faced this issue earlier. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Alam

Answer (score 1):

Check the Scope of Dataview Webpart and current Dataview webpart List presence not availble in subsite.

Comment: yes the list is present in the site collection and master page will have to use that list only.

Comment: Can you add a same list into the current subsite and check it is working or not

Answer (score -1):

http://www.neilrichards.net/ramble/dataview-web-parts-in-your-master-page-cause-errors-on-subsites please check this out..! This could solve your issue...

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.